# Running docker instance not resolving gradle dependencies when calling another class

Tags: docker, gradle, thrift

Hey guys I'm having this problem when using docker and gradle. I encountered NoClassDefFoundError when running a docker container after successful build. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk
RUN mkdir "Verteiltes_System"
WORKDIR "Verteiltes_System"
COPY src/main/java/Bank/src/* src/main/java/Bank/src/
COPY src/main/java/TCP/src/* src/main/java/TCP/src/
COPY src/main/java/Stock/* src/main/java/Stock/
COPY src/main/java/Thrift/* src/main/java/Thrift/
COPY src/* src/
COPY build/libs/* build/libs/


COPY .gradle .gradle
COPY gradlew .
COPY gradle gradle


COPY build.gradle .

RUN ./gradlew build

src/main/java/Bank/src/BankTCP.java src/main/java/Bank/src/ClientHandler.java src/main/java/Bank/src/Bank.java
CMD ["java", "-cp", "build/classes/java/main/Stock:build/classes/java/main/TCP/src:build/classes/java/main/Bank/src:build/classes/java/main/", "Bank.src.Bank"]
```

and here's where the Bank calls BankThriftHandler:

```
public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.securities = new HashMap<>();
        this.reserves = 1000000;
        this.isBankrupt = false;
        setTotalValue();

        try {
            bankThriftHandler = new BankThriftHandler(this);
            bankThriftHandler.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And in BankThriftHandler the following classes are imported:

```
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.server.TServer;
import org.apache.thrift.server.TSimpleServer;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.*;
```

When running docker it stops at "bankThriftHandler = new BankThriftHandler(this);" and yielded a

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportException.
```

I tested by importing these same classes in Bank and it still worked until reaching that BankThriftHandler constructor part. It seems that these dependencies are not carried over when going from Bank to BankthriftHandler

Comment: Your `java -cp ...` classpath only seems to include your application code, but not any of the dependencies.  Does Gradle build a "fat" jar that includes all of the library dependencies that you can run directly?  Does a similar `java` command work on your host system without Docker?

Comment: I found a .jar file in `build/libs` that has the name of the project. I included it in the class path but it still yielded the same error. The same `java` command also doesn't work on the host system without docker. Somehow the called class couldn't find the gradle dependencies

Comment: anyways thanks alot for your `fatJar` suggestions. I added this fatJar task in gradle:
```tasks.register('fatJar', Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': "Bank.src.Bank"
    }
    archiveBaseName = 'Bank'
    from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}```

and everything now works just as expected